# Should we **always** skip reviews when we are unfamiliar with the topic?

Tags: discussion, review

Every now and then, I encounter a First Post or Late Answer where I have no knowledge whatsoever concerning the topic at hand. Unless its obvious that the post is blatantly worthless (e.g. `"Have you found the answer yet?"` or `"ssssszzzggggiclllll kjhk"`) I tend to skip these, but sometimes the situation is more complicated.

For instance, some questions can be answered (perhaps not particularly thoroughly, but answered nonetheless) in [one sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694053/1530508), while others may require [absolutely gargantuan explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1530508) in order to be complete. When I see a one-line question, my instinct is to request further explanation, but when I know nothing of the topic I don't even know if that's appropriate.

It's even worse for reviews of questions, when what seems like a perfectly good question  to me could in fact be answered just by reading the wikipedia summary on the topic at hand, and what looks like a very poor question ends up receiving hundreds of upvotes because I didn't understand some subtlety of what was being asked due to my inexperience in the question's topic.

So in general which would be the better choice:

- Use my best judgement when I can, and skip only when I am 100% lost as to what to do.
- Immediately skip any post that falls outside the areas I am knowledgeable about

  Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: I doubt there's a single right answer here. Depends on the situation. So, use your best judgement, which it sounds like you are already doing. :)

Comment: Review when you feel reasonably certain about the decision. No need to constrain yourself with nonexistant rules.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with the topic, you *should* still be able to identify the following:

**All review queues:**

- All forms of **spam**.
- *Very* low quality posts.

**First Posts:**

- Code that requires formatting. Often times the code just needs to be indented.
- Blatantly obvious off-topic questions.

**Late Answers:**

- Questions posted as answers.
- Replies to existing answers. (Often unable to comment, these are attempts to thank an answer)

**Suggested edits queue:**

- Vandalism edits.
- Radical edits that introduce dramatic changes.
- Edits attempting to reply to the post.

**Close queue:**

- Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource.
- Primarily opinion-based questions (e.g. best way to; worst; favorite etc.)
- Obvious duplicates

---

It's worth noting that you can also **filter** reviews by tags too!

> [image: filter img]

Comment: Cool, i did not know about the ability to filter by tags.